# Регулярные выражения. Разрешение символов и букв

Tags: php

Есть код, который разрешает русские и английские буквы, а также цифры.
Можно как-нибудь сделать так, чтобы разрешалось еще использовать пробел и знаки "-" и "_"?
Насчет двух последних символов не уверен, но пробел точно не разрешается.
Буду очень благодарен за помощь!

```
if (preg_match("/^[а-яА-ЯёЁa-zA-Z0-9\-_]+$/iu",$name)) {
//
}
```

Comment: Ну так добавь в список пробел. Но учти что строка из десяти пробелов тоже пройдет проверку.

Comment: дефис последним добавляется в набор. а флаг `i` - регистронезависимости, так что А-Я/A-Z можете убрать. цифры заменить на \d. в целом английское с цифрами и подчеркиванием это `\w`. То есть все ваше выражение можно описать как `[\s\wа-яё-]`, где пробельные символы это `\s`

Answer (score 0):

```
if (preg_match("/^[\s\-_а-яА-Яa-zA-Z0-9ёЁ]+$/", $name)) {
    // Your code
}
```

Comment: Ваш ответ можно улучшить с помощью дополнительной информации. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] для добавления подробностей, например, цитат или документации, чтобы другие могли подтвердить правильность вашего ответа. Вы можете найти дополнительную информацию о том, как писать хорошие ответы [в Справке](/help/how-to-answer).